# uniswap router address in Goerli testnet

Tags: etherscan, uniswap, goerli

hello guys any body know what is the uniswap router address in Goerli testnet? i checked the following addresses but none of them worked.

0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984
0x3fC91A3afd70395Cd496C647d5a6CC9D4B2b7FAD
0x4648a43B2C14Da09FdF82B161150d3F634f40491
0xBa60b6e6fF25488308789E6e0A65D838be34194e
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can find their deployment address in Goerli testnet in here: https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments.

For swap router, according to the doc link above, the swap router of Uniswap in Goerli testnet is: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45#code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I really followed your advice and added it to my code. I added the constructor of the code in the question, but when I press the deploy button, I encounter a gas limit error. This error arises when the router address does not match the testnet. As I mentioned earlier, I am using the Goerli testnet.

Comment: Could you please share more information about your program?